# Calling Webservice from another server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I have created a web service, called `MailSerderWS.asmx` having code in `AppCode/MailSerderWS.cs` its working fine on the local PC, but i have some questions regarding its usage on Production:

1. Basically i am creating this service to send email from my server, as my server does not supports asp, so cannot use coding, so i am planning to place the webservice on my friends server and call the webservice to send mails from my site.
2. Before i deploy this webservice on my friends server, i want to check this webservice on my local machine, with my html webpage. below is the jquery i am running.
   But it never postbacks and hence does not sends mail to my inbox.

   How shall i be able to upload this webservice on my friends live server, so that i can utilize this webservice in my html page and also how i will be consuming it, because i think if i use above ajax method it will never execute

Code for item 2:

```
$("#btnSendMail").click(function(){
                     $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://audiomedia.dev.asentechdev1.com/MailSenderWS.asmx/SendMail",
                    data: "{'sendermail':'aelectricwala52@gmail.com', 'type':'standalone app', 'body':'success'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                      alert(msg)
                    },
                    error: function(msg){
                        alert(msg.responseText);
                    }
                  });
                  })
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see two syntax errors. Try this:

```
$("#btnSendMail").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost:16189/MailSenderWS.asmx/SendMail",
                        data: "{'sendermail':'aelectricwala52@gmail.com', 'type':'standalone app', 'body':'success'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg) {
                          alert(msg)
                        },
                        error: function(msg){
                            alert(msg);
                        }
                      });
                  });
```

A while back I wrote an article about asmx webservice methods and calling it from Jquery. This might help you: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/8/asp.net/how-to-use-jquery-to-call-a-webservice-asmx-method

**Edit**:
Based on your update, I tried to call it per Ajax, but that didn't work for me either. The service seems to be deployed correctly, because you can call the URL in the browser. I added your service as a Service Reference, called your method and used [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture the communication.

Connecting to the server is no problem, however the response from the service indicates an authentication problem associated with your e-mail account:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SendMailResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<SendMailResult>
Fail Reason: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. sk1sm6949585pbc.0
</SendMailResult>
</SendMailResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Try sending e-mails from your local computer without the Webservice and see that you get it working. Afterwards redeploy and you should be ready to go.
I'd also advise you to change the Url of your webservice, because now that you've posted it online and there is no authentication involved, someone might abuse it.

**Edit2**:
I'll tell you how I used Fiddler. First you need to download and install it.

Create a new .net Application (ConsoleApplication for instance). In the `Solution Explorer`, rightclick on the project and click `Add Service Reference`. Use the URL  `http://audiomedia.dev.asentechdev1.com/MailSender.asmx`

This generates some code in your project.

Start Fiddler and execute this code in your ConsoleApplication (depending on the generated name, you need to adapt this sample):

```
    ServiceReference1.MailSenderSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.MailSenderSoapClient();
    client.SendMail();
```

Inside Fiddler you'll see Web Sessions on the left site. A new entry with your url was added. Click on it. On the right sight in the bottom area you'll see the message

> Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection.
>   Click here to transform.

If you click on that message and select the TextView TabPage, you'll get this result from your service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SendMailResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<SendMailResult>Success</SendMailResult>
</SendMailResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: hi @citronas can you share what are the 2 syntax error you found, i am unable to makeout.

Comment: now i am using the webservice from the server, i have added the asmx file into the root directory of another site (which is on my friends server). in the jquery.ajax call url method now i am passing: (http://audiomedia.dev.asentechdev1.com/MailSenderWS.asmx/Sendmail), but still this is not working, i am not even getting error message using error : function(msg){alert(msg.responseText)} can you please help

Comment: There was no comma between success and error, and a semicolon was missing at the end

Comment: ok i have changed the content. you can see my updated answer with the updated codes, still its not working

Comment: hi @citronas i have updated the the Service (http://audiomedia.dev.asentechdev1.com/MailSender.asmx/SendMail) can you tell me how shall i check it with fiddler, also this time webservice does not require any parameter

Comment: I edited my answer. Calling your webservice now works. I'm glad I could be of help. Feel free to upvote and accept my answer ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22716/discussion-between-abbas-and-citronas)